# how to display log file in running application which will create on server

Tags: java, logging, log4j

how to display log file in running application which will create on server

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\loging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=debug, file, stdout
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I am using logger for our application. this log file generate on server.. now i read this log file and want to display log in our application

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to append the logs into xml file and after debugging go to that xml file and read it